# Have fade-out effect to differenciate age of questions

Tags: feature-request, design

Would it be within the design ideology of Stackoverflow to have the new questions' background initially be like this:

> rgba(250,251,90,0.5)

And then over time the background fades to something like this:

> rgba(0,0,0,0.5)

This way you immediately know if the question is older or newer. It would really tie in with the site's logo:

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe that the age of a question is important information that should be highlighted?

Comment: Some people like to see what's on the bottom of the stack? I think a temporal dynamic would be interesting.

Comment: Do you have evidence to show that "some people" is enough people to warrant bringing more attention to a question's age? Is what you're referring to something beyond going to the [last page of questions sorted by age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=627427&sort=newest)? Note that an ideal question here is one that does not degrade in quality over time; the age *should* be irrelevant. Is there a more fundamental issue you are trying to address?

Comment: New questions automatically appear at the top of the main page, and gradually go down the page until it reaches the bottom and it moves to page 2 (and so on and so forth). What specific improvement do you feel would occur by adding fading colors? We already have the *temporal dynamic* of it descending and then disappearing from the main page.

Comment: rgba(250,251,90,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5) - Why not just say "yellow" and "grey"? As for the suggestion itself, I don't think it would look good to have the background color change on every page.

Answer (score 8):

This wouldn't likely work. Here's why (at least in my opinion):

Look at some of the most popular questions. They've had thousands of views, and they've been asked more than six years ago. Many are still active, receiving comments, up votes, and even answers. They are a great help to the worldwide community. What would happen if the background would gray out?

To many, it would seem awkward having different colours on the site. Some may not understand it at first, however once this implementation would get more exposure, it wouldn't make sense. For a programming site, it may imply that the questions may be with older software, the answers suggested could likely be deprecated... and so on.

Also, the "whiteness" helps keep the site clean. We don't want a million colours: there's links, icons and a whole bunch of stuff that this could interfere. Undertaking this would be massive.

So, here's my opinion: This doesn't make sense and it shouldn't happen.